# I need help formatting code created in Microsoft Visual Studio to work in Xcode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xcode4, formatting

I have a small bit of code I made on Microsoft Visual studio that is a simple program I used to teach someone the fundamentals of C++. I am moving to Xcode and it is new to me. I need help reformatting this code so it can be run on a mac. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random> //this needs to be included for the rand() function
#include <time.h> //this needs to be included for the seed time
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
//PAB

int random_in_range(int a, int b)//this function will generate a random number between specified range
{
    return (a+rand()%(b-a+1));
}

void hangman(){
    char guess;
    string word="";
    string hidden ="";
    int strikesLeft= 0;


    int random = random_in_range(1,15);

    switch(random){
    case 1:
        word = "bacon";
        hidden ="?????";
        strikesLeft=5;
        break;
    case 2:
        word = "computer";
        hidden ="????????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 3:
        word = "human";
        hidden = "?????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 4:
        word = "desk";
        hidden = "????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 5:
        word = "card";
        hidden = "????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 6: 
        word="keyboard";
        hidden = "????????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 7:
        word="phone";
        hidden="?????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 8:
        word="mouse";
        hidden="?????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 9:
        word="camp";
        hidden="????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 10:
        word="captain";
        hidden="???????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 11:
        word="brother";
        hidden="???????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 12:
        word="beauty";
        hidden="??????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 13:
        word="cave";
        hidden="????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 14:
        word="children";
        hidden="????????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
    case 15:
        word="action";
        hidden="??????";
        strikesLeft=7;
        break;
}

    bool gameOver=false;
    int pos;
    //add strike counter

    cout << "                            ***WELCOME TO HANGMAN***" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Try to guess the word in question marks. But watch out, if you use too many letters not in the word, you will lose." << endl;
    cout << "You start with " << strikesLeft << " strikes." << endl;
    cout << "Good luck..." << endl;

    do{
        cout << "Word is " << hidden << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter guess: ";
        cin >> guess;

        pos = word.find_first_of(guess);


        if(pos!=-1)
            hidden[pos]=guess;


        else{
            strikesLeft--;
            cout <<"Sorry, " << guess << " is not in this word." << endl;
            cout <<"You have " << strikesLeft << " strikes left." << endl; //also tell them strikes remaining
        }

        if(hidden==word || strikesLeft==0)
            gameOver=true;

    }
    while(gameOver==false);

    if(strikesLeft==0)
    cout << "Game Over! You failed..." << endl;
    cout << "The word was " << word << "." << endl;

    if(strikesLeft>0)
    cout << "Congrats! You completed my game with " << strikesLeft << " strikes left." << endl;



    system("PAUSE");


}

int main(){

cout << "" << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "                                  *WELCOME*" << endl;

        system("color 0c");

        Sleep(500);

        cout << "                              **TO**" << endl;

        system("color 0f");

        Sleep(500);

        cout << "                     ***PAB***";




        system("color 0a");

        Sleep(3000);

        system("cls");
        cout << "" << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

        cout << "                             P";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "E";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "R";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "S";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "O";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "N";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "A";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "L";
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << " A";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "W";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "E";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "S";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "O";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "M";
        Sleep(100);
        cout << "E";
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << " B";
        Sleep(150);
        cout << "O";
        Sleep(150);
        cout << "T";
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");

        system("color 08");

        cout << "Program loading.";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading..";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading...";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading.";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading..";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading...";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading.";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Program loading..";
        Sleep(500);
        system("cls");



    srand(time(NULL));//seeds the random number generator. Do this before calling the randomInRange function
        string name;
        int friends;
        int DecimalArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,22,555,85,18,741}; //Create an array of decimal numbers.

        system ("color 0f");

        cout << "Enter name:  ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Hi " << name << "." << " My name is PAB, your personal awesome bot." << endl; 

        cout << "Now tell me, how many friends do you have? " << endl;
        cin >> friends;

        if(friends >=75 && friends <300)
            cout << "Gee, " << friends << " friends is a lot. But you could always have one more...ME!!" << endl; 
        if(friends >300)
            cout << "Yeah, maybe on Facebook...But we should still be friends!" << endl;

        if(friends <75)
            cout << "Man, you totally need more friends. I can be one of them!" << endl;


        int randomNum=random_in_range(1,50);
        int numGuess;

        cout << "Now that we're friends, I want to play a game. Now, pick a number between 1 and 50. " << endl;
        do{ //dowhile loop using "getting closer" for when your getting closer to the number
            cin >> numGuess;
            if(numGuess >50)
                cout << "Can you read? It clearly says between 1 and 50. " << endl;
            if(numGuess >randomNum)
                cout << "That's too high guess again. " << endl;
            if(numGuess <randomNum)
                cout << "That's too low please guess again. " << endl;

        }while(numGuess !=randomNum);
        system("cls");
                cout << "Congratulations! You found out my number." << endl;
                cout << "Okay, I agree that was stupid. But, I have another game!" << endl << endl << endl;
        hangman();

        system("cls");
        cout << "Thanks for playing with me today! I hope you had fun." << endl;
        cout << "In the future I will have new games and jokes." << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "                                   THE END" << endl;

        Sleep(5000);

        system("cls");
        system("color 08");
        cout << "v1.7" << endl;
        cout << "[copyright]" << endl;
        cout << "Ethan MacCumber 2012" << endl;




    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Um... You can't just "reformat" code to make MS C++ code "work in XCode on a Mac". You're asking people to rewrite your code in a different language, and that's not what we do here at StackOverflow.

Comment: It's the same language. I am just not familiar with c++ in a mac environment. You don't have to rewrite my code to make it work on Xcode. I only have to change a couple of things for it to run.

Comment: I apologize if what I say is ignorant. You seem to be much more knowledgable about C++ than me.

Comment: No, XCode is not just a change of a "couple of things for it to run". XCode is not even close to being "the same language". But if it is, you shouldn't have any problem quickly making those "couple of changes", so what do you need us for?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong that I can't compile this code in Xcode. Are you familier with other Mac compatible softwares that could run this? Can QT do that?

Comment: You need to provide some compile errors at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your major problem is that your code isn't entirely standard C++. You used C++ code that is only available on Windows, the functions in the windows.h and conio.h header files. Any functions in those header files won't work on a Mac.

If you want your code to run on Mac OS X, comment out the includes of windows.h and conio.h. Commenting out the includes of the Windows-specific headers will generate a ton of compiler errors, which should show you where the Windows-specific code is. Get rid of that code and stick with code that is standard C++, like cin and cout. From a quick glance at your code, the calls to Sleep() and System("cls") won't work on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any equivalent headers and calls for the Sleep() and System("cls") that are on a mac or standard C++?

Comment: I don't do a lot of C++ programming so I can't tell you the equivalent functions. You should take a look at ncurses, which is a Unix library that is similar to using the conio.h functions.